# Comma separation not working Typescript (Angular 8)

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a html event emitter as follows:

```
  `(keypress)="numberComma($event, i)"`
```

in typescript I have the following function:

```js
const charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode; 
if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) 
{ 
    return false; 
} 
const numString = event.target.value.replace(/,/g, ''); console.log(numString); 
const num = Number(numString).toLocaleString('en-US'); this.captiveExposure = num; 
return true;    
}
```

It should separate a number after 1000's digits using commas. Example: 1000000 should be 1,000,000. But it only allows me to enter 4 digits now and when I enter the fifth digit it overwrite the 4 digits. Ex: if I enter 1234 and then press 5, in form field it shows only 5.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve? To get your value into currency format, because there are much easier ways.

Comment: You could use the `DecimalPipe`.  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s7his2

Comment: Official [doc](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe) for DecimalPipe